# What is the preferred strategy/workaround for introducing legacy database entities in Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

Is there a good practice to introduce existing legacy database tables/entities into a JHipster project? 
The idea I had was to create the JPA entities that look exactly like the existing entities and then use the generated artifacts as per normal. Will this possibly work?

Comment: Have you tried generator-jhipster-db-helper module?

Comment: Not yet, thank you for the response. As far as I can tell, it mainly renames an existing entity? Ah ok, I get it now....just to confirm....the process is. I have an existing entity..run the db-helper, update the field names etc and I will then get a .json entity file and from that, I can regenerate entity and I will get all the wiring for free as per normal? Have I got it right?

Comment: that's the idea, I did not test it myself and it hasn't evolve recently, so it might not work. Otherwise creating .jhipster/*.json files or jdl file manually and then generating code can work if your existing entities match JHipster conventions as much as possible, I did it successfully starting from a Ruby on Rails application database.

Comment: just gave that a try, unfortunately some of my legacy tables dont follow good standards and they dont have an id column. This kind of messes me up. I might just have to write some spring-jdbc wrappers for those few tables. It's mostly read-only anyways, I dont have to do updates on those legacy tables, thankfully. I appreciate your help. In this case its going to be easier to just drop them into my jhipster project using standard spring-jdbc wrappers....painful, but it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I opted for just creating a view of all the underlying tables I needed in my query. The steps I followed were:

1. create the view on the DB,
2. Generate the entity using JHipster, with exactly the same fields.
3. Strip out the Update ad Create and Delete functions and we have a read-only view page with all the data you need and all the fields displaying, done.

Now I can add my own routers and buttons, to allow other specific operations/flow. This page was my inspiration: https://www.javabullets.com/calling-database-views-from-spring-data-jpa/